# Why is my React show/hide label not updating correctly?

Tags: reactjs, input, label, jsx, textinput

The label is editable: When click on the label, input text field will be shown and label field is hidden. After the text field has lost focus, the label field will be shown and text field will be hidden. I am having issue where label does not update with the new text input value.

The add component button will create a new component and place it on top of the list. Having issue where the newly created component is place below the list which has input text shown and label hidden.

After added multiple new components, when I click on one of the label, the text field is automatically updated with other text. I have tried to debug it but cannot resolve it.

```
import React from 'react';  
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome'; 

export default class Dynamic extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super(); 
    this.state = { 
      arr: [],
      text:"LABEL",
      saveDisabled: true, 
      editing: []
    };
  }

  handleSort(sortedArray) {
    this.setState({
      arr: sortedArray
    });
  }

  save(){  
  }

  closePopup() { 
  }

  handleAddElement() { 
    this.textInput.value : 'LABEL';
    this.state.arr.unshift('LABEL');

    this.setState({ 
      saveDisabled: false,
    });   
  }

  handleRemoveElement(index) {
    const newArr = this.state.arr.slice();
    newArr.splice(index, 1);

    this.setState({
      arr: newArr,
      saveDisabled: false
    });
  }

  changeLabel(index){     
    this.setState({ 
      saveDisabled: false 
    });
    console.log(index);
    this.state.editing[index] = true;
    console.log("changelabel");
  }

  textChanged(index) {
    console.log("txtval: "+this.textInput.value);
    this.setState({ text: this.textInput.value});
    this.state.arr[index] = this.textInput.value;
     this.setState({
       arr: arr
     });
    console.log(this.state.arr);
  }

  inputLostFocus(index) { 
    this.state.editing[index] = false;
  }

  keyPressed(event) {
    if(event.key == 'Enter') {
      this.inputLostFocus();
    }
    this.inputLostFocus();
    console.log("key");
  }

  render() {
    function renderItem(num, index) {

        return ( 
          <DemoItem  className="dynamic-item" > 
              <FontAwesome className='th' name='  th' onClick={this.handleRemoveElement.bind(this, index)}/>
              <div name="name" className={(index==0)||this.state.editing[index] ? "hideElement": "displayElement"} onClick={this.changeLabel.bind(this,index)}>{this.state.arr[index]}</div>
              <input autofocus name="name" type="text" className={(index==0)||this.state.editing[index] ? "displayElement": "hideElement"} onChange={this.textChanged.bind(this, index)} onBlur={this.inputLostFocus.bind(this,index)}
              onKeyPress={this.keyPressed.bind(this,index)} defaultValue={this.state.arr[index]} ref={(input) => {this.textInput = input;}} />  
              <FontAwesome className='trash-o' name='trash-o' onClick={this.handleRemoveElement.bind(this, index)}/>
         </DemoItem>
        ) 
    } 

    return ( 
      <div className="demo-container">
        <div className="dynamic-demo">
          <h2 className="demo-title">
            Tasks
            <button disabled={this.state.saveDisabled} onClick={::this.save}>Save</button>
            <button onClick={::this.handleAddElement}>Add Component</button>
          </h2>
          <Sortable className="vertical-container" direction="vertical" dynamic>
            {this.state.arr.map(renderItem, this)}   
          </Sortable> 
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


displayElement {
  display: inline;
}
.hideElement{
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your bug is in your `textChanged` function, try this instead:

```js
textChanged(index) {
  console.log("txtval: " + this.textInput.value);
  // this.state.arr[index] = this.textInput.value; <= bug
  const newArray = [...this.state.arr];
  newArray[index] = this.textInput.value;
  this.setState({
    arr: newArray,
    text: this.textInput.value
  });
  // console.log(this.state.arr); <= don't check here, check in your render method
}
```

Two changes:

1. Modify the state via `this.setState`, not via `this.state.arr`.
2. Setting state in one `this.setState` action for cleaner code.
3. Commenting out console log of this.state since the state hasn't fully updated yet until the next life cycle.  Instead, console log the state in your render method.

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your tips! It's quite helpful. I try debug, the function for textChanged(index) refers to this.textInput.value which does not match the correct array index. Do you know if I can set specific ref id/classname for each input field, as I'm using {this.state.arr.map(renderItem, this)} to render the repeated components in the renderItem()

Comment: Yes, you can set specific ref values for each input field.  As many as you want.  Did I answer your question and can you accept my answer?